# Where to store config for a rails plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I'm working on a plugin for rails to provide some simple diagnostic information about external systems for purposes of monitoring etc. primarily as an exercise to learn more about rails.

I need to know where config variables for this type of rails plugin belongs, in this case I need to store an array of ip addresses and ports that point at these external services so that I can access it in my plugins controllers e.g.

```
['127.0.0.1:12345', '192.168.1.1:54321']
```

I'm currently using Rails 3.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a new file in config/initializers, e.g. globals.rb:

```
EXTERNAL_SERVICE_IP_1 = "some ip"
```

Answer (score 3):

There are many  answers to this question depending on what you really expect:

- define a constant in a class or a module (with or without yml)
- define two methods in a class or a module: one to get a variable (with default value) and another to set and change the value

How do you want to use it?

Comment: Rails has a built in module for helping with configurations that makes it easier to do option 2. https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/configurable.rb

Comment: @Beerlington: you should post this as an answer, it's a valuable resource I forgot to mention

Comment: It's basically doing what your second suggestion is getting at. Didn't feel like hijacking your response when a comment could suffice :)

Comment: In my case the array of services would be fairly static, so having them as a constant would be best, it's not something I'll need to change at runtime.